# How to fix Bevy ECS queries conflicting even with filters

Tags: rust, bevy

I am trying to execute the below two queries in a bevy system function.

```
fn move_player(
    mut player_query: Query<(&mut Velocity, &mut Transform, &SpriteSize, &Player), With<PlayerId>>,
    wall_query: Query<(&Transform, &SpriteSize), With<Barrier>>,
) {
    for (mut player_velocity, mut player_tf, player_size, player) in player_query.iter_mut() {
        for (wall_tf, wall_size) in wall_query.iter() {
        }
    }
}
```

I inserted the `PlayerId` component to the Player entity and the `Barrier` component to the Wall entities when spawning them. The `PlayerId` is not inserted in Wall entities and the `Barrier` component is not inserted in the Player entity.

When I run the above function I get the error below;

> thread 'main' panicked at 'error[B0001]: Query<(&mut
> bevy_transform::components::transform::Transform,
> &bevy_fantasy::Sprite Size),
> bevy_ecs::query::filter::With<bevy_fantasy::Barrier>> in system
> bevy_fantasy::player::move_player accesses component( s)
> bevy_transform::components::transform::Transform in a way that
> conflicts with a previous system parameter. Consider using
> `Without<T>` to create disjoint Queries or merging conflicting Queries
> into a `ParamSet`.

Why are the 2 queries conflicting when I filter them using unique components?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using

```rust
mut player_query: Query<(&mut Velocity, &mut Transform, &SpriteSize, &Player), With<PlayerId>>,
wall_query: Query<(&Transform, &SpriteSize), With<Barrier>>,
```

All entities that have `Transform`, `Velocity`, `SpriteSize`, `Player`, `PlayerId`, and `Barrier` components are in both queries.
There is no way for Rust or Bevy to tell that there aren't any such Entities.

Getting mutable references to `Transform` would therefore be [undefined behaviour](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html) because it violates the aliasing rules of mutable references.

To fix it just follow one of the suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I have had this problem myself. As @cafce25 you need to follow the suggestion of the error message. If you add a Without to one of the queries it can exclude the results of the other query.

Here I've modified your snippet to use `Without<Barrier>` in the `player_query`.

```
fn move_player(
    mut player_query: Query<(&mut Velocity, &mut Transform, &SpriteSize, &Player), With<PlayerId>, Without<Barrier>,
    wall_query: Query<(&Transform, &SpriteSize), With<Barrier>>,
) {
    for (mut player_velocity, mut player_tf, player_size, player) in player_query.iter_mut() {
        for (wall_tf, wall_size) in wall_query.iter() {
        }
    }
}
```